# Напиши программу, которая разделяет запятыми на тройки (считая справа) натуральное число

Tags: python

Напиши программу, которая разделяет запятыми на тройки (считая справа) натуральное число.
Программа на вход получает натуральное число.

Если в числе менее трёх знаков, то программы выводи текст: NO.

Пример работы программы.
Входные данные: 14875
Выходные данные: 14,875

Входные данные: 148
Выходные данные: NO

Comment: С такими заявками - на фриланс...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Громаднейшая программа, но работает!***

```
a=list(input())
b=a[:]
s=0
sc=1
while True:
    if sc == 1 and len(a)<=3:
        print('NO')
        break
    if s-3 >= 0-len(b) and sc==1:
        s-=3
        a.insert(s, ',')
    elif s-3 >= 0-len(b):
        s-=4
        a.insert(s, ',')
        
    else: 
        print(''.join(a))
        break
    sc+=1
```